# Simple for loop does not seem work properly

Tags: javascript, function, loops, push

I'm having a trouble to get an array with numbers from 1 to 16 randomly without repetition.
I made **num** array to put numbers from **createNum** function.

The **createNum** function has a for loop which gets numbers from 1 to 16 until if statement push 16 numbers into **num** array.

At the end, I run createNum() and display numbers on the web. 
While I'm making this code it sometimes worked but now it's not working.

can somebody point out where I made mistakes?

```
let num = [];

function createNum () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 15;) {
        let numGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
        if (!num.includes(numGen)) {
            num.push(numGen);
            i++;
        };
    };
}
console.log(createNum());
document.getElementById("selectedNumbersShownHere").innerHTML = num;
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Thank you everybody, this problem was fixed! I understood there're many ways to fix the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Math.random()` never returns 1, so at the end `Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)` will returns maximum 14 and adding it to 1 will get you maximum 15.
Use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.floor` i.e

```
let num = [];

function createNum () {
    for (i = 0; i <=15;) {
        let numGen = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 16);
        console.log(numGen)
        if (!num.includes(numGen)) {
            num.push(numGen);
             i++;
        };
    };
}
console.log(createNum());
document.getElementById("selectedNumbersShownHere").innerHTML = num;
console.log(num);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just knew what ceil is and think your answer fix the problem very well. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop seems never finish because the probability to get the last value is very low, and never can happen in a short time.

Plus :
**your formula is wrong** : `let numGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;`
and should be................: `let numGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 1;` **value 16**

see => [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

do this:

```js
function createNum()
  {
  let num =[], lastOne =136; // 136 = 1 +2 +3 + ... +16
  for (;;)
    {
    let numGen = Math.floor(Math.random() *16) +1;
    if (!num.includes(numGen))
      {
      lastOne -= numGen;
      if (num.push(numGen)>14) break;
      }
    }
  num.push(lastOne); // add the missing one (optimizing)
  return num;
  }

let unOrdered_16_vals = createNum();

/*
document.getElementById("selectedNumbersShownHere").textContent = unOrdered_16_vals.join('');
*/

console.log( JSON.stringify( unOrdered_16_vals ), 'length=', unOrdered_16_vals.length  );
console.log(  'in order = ', JSON.stringify( unOrdered_16_vals.sort((a,b)=>a-b) ) );
```

remark : The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array **and returns the new length** of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`for (i = 0; i <= 15;)` generates 16 numbers, but `Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1` only have 15 possible values (1~15).

A `shuffle` function is recommended. Your function would be slow if you generate a large size shuffled array.

[How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I'll learn shuffle function you proposed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that your looking for **16** distinct numbers out of **15** possible values.

The reason for this is that `Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;` will only return values between 1 and 15, but your loop will run until you have 16 unique values, so you enter into an infinite loop.

What you're basically trying to achieve is randomly shuffle an array with values from 1 to 16.

One common solution with good performance (`O(n)`) is the so-called [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Here is code that addresses your requirements based on an [implementation by Mike Bostock](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/):

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  let m = array.length, t, i;

  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

// create array with values from 1 to 16
const array = Array(16).fill().map((_, i) => i + 1);

// shuffle
const shuffled = shuffle(array);

console.log(shuffled);
```

Compared to your approach and the approach of other answers to this question, the code above will only make 15 calls to the random number generator, while the others will make anywhere between 16 and an infinite number of calls<sup><sup>(1)</sup></sup>.

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> In probability theory, this is called the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). For a value *n* of 16, on average 54 calls would have to be made to collect all 16 values.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me have some time to understand your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this :**

```
    let num = [];

function createNum () {
    for (i = 0; num.length <= 17; i++) {
        let numGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 1;
        if (!num.includes(numGen)) {
            num.push(numGen);
        };
    };
}
console.log(createNum());
document.getElementById("selectedNumbersShownHere").innerHTML = num;
console.log(num);
```

Please find the working demo [here](https://playcode.io/481372)

Comment: thanks, SelakaN. It works, but I need to get 16 numbers (I want to let the code run till it gets 16 different numbers).

Comment: I can not yet. because it's not yet solving my question.

Comment: You're asking for upvotes and acceptance, and then you'll provide the answer?

Comment: yes, but if I use your update it doesn't make 16 numbers. your update now only runs the code 16 times. That's where I'm having headaches at...

Comment: Op has stated 'SelakaN. It works' Why not ask for that. I have so many bad experiences where OP's never marked it as correct leaving for good solutions.

Comment: Updated my answer please check now @Kay.T

Answer (score 0):

```
This is an infinite loop error. Because your loop variable "i" is always less than or equal to 15. and your i++ is inside the if statement. You can achieve it in multiple ways. Below is one sample.

let num = [];

function createNum () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 15;) {
        let numGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
        if (!num.includes(numGen)) {
            num.push(numGen);
        };
         i++;
    };
}
console.log(createNum());
document.getElementById("selectedNumbersShownHere").innerHTML = num;
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I'm "passionate" about this question, and I can't resist presenting a second answer, which is IMHO: the best!

```js
function createNum ()
  {
  let num = []
  for (let len=0;len<16;)
    {
    let numGen = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 16)
    if (!num.includes(numGen))
      { len = num.push(numGen) }
    }
  return num
  }

let unOrdered = createNum();

console.log( JSON.stringify( unOrdered ) );

/*
document.getElementById("selectedNumbersShownHere").textContent = unOrdered_16_vals.join('');
*/
```